# Past tenses with a present tense

Tags: tense, past-simple, present-simple

I watched a movie and later discussed it with my friend. Is the example below correct?

> I recognised the actor today. Before I hadn't known he is there.

Or is it better to say:

> I recognised the actor today. Before I hadn't known he was there.

To me, the first option sounds better.

Comment: I think I'll say"I had never seen him in there before yesterday".

Comment: Where is "there"? It would be better to just write that ("in that movie" or such).

Answer (score 1):

The verb should match the time frame of the comment.  Since you are talking about a *past* event, you should use the past tense of the verb.

> Before, I **didn't** even notice he **was** there.

or

> Before, I **didn't** even know he **was** in that movie.